# how to check a word againest multiple text boxes

Tags: c#

My Form

[image: screenshot]

The entered word in the text box must be matched to the any one of the above randomly character generated text boxes and the word must contain char which is in yellow color.

Please help solve these two validations

1. Checking whether any of the character in the word
   contains,character in yellow text box.
2. Remaining characters in the words is present in any of the text
   boxes.

Comment: @selhia are you familiar with the `string.Contains()` method

Comment: Have you tried searching "C# string contains character" on google?

Comment: Looks like [tag:homework]-- Why is it the first thing people do in class is set the dialog color. I wish instructors conveyed UX rules, too.

Comment: I wish instructors teach them to search before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all you need is to get the value of the label that shows in Yellow and do something like this.

```
string holdWord = textBox1.Text; //BEEP
char charToCheck = Convert.ToChar(label1.Text); // 'E'

bool result = holdWord.Contains(charToCheck); //TRUE
```

Comment: Please do not encourage questions asked by someone that hasn't search for an answer.

Comment: Good point, still, it is a question and it deserves an answer.

Comment: no one prefers to ask help for others unless he tries by his own....thanks for supporting me @Dayan and i accepted your answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of handing over the solution....

**First Case**

This meets the criteria (best I can tell).

```
Boolean IsAcceptableWord(String input, Char yellowLetter, params Char[] textBoxLetters)
{
    // Short-circuit: Empty is empty
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return false;

    // yellow letter
    if (!input.Contains(yellowLetter.ToString())) return false;

    // textBox letters
    foreach (var inputLetter in input)
    {
        if (textBoxLetters.Contains(inputLetter)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Second Case**

This one is a bit more elaborate. The criteria i used were:

- Must not be empty string.
- Must have yellow character present only 1 time.
- Remaining letters must be made up of single uses of each of the textBox characters. (Given your example, you can't use `Q` nor can you use `Z` more than twice).

```cs
Boolean IsAcceptableWord2(String input, Char yellowLetter, params Char[] textBoxLetters)
{
    // Short-circuit: must not be empty
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Validation
    if (textBoxLetters == null || textBoxLetters.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("textBoxLetters");
    }
    if (!Char.IsLetter(yellowLetter))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be a letter", "yellowLetter");
    }
    if (textBoxLetters.Any(x => !Char.IsLetter(x)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be all letters", "textBoxLetters");
    }

    // Normalization
    input = input.ToLowerInvariant();
    yellowLetter = Char.ToLower(yellowLetter);
    textBoxLetters = textBoxLetters.Select(x => Char.ToLower(x)).ToArray();
    var inputCharArray = input.ToCharArray();

    // Comparisons
    var yellowLetterCount = inputCharArray.Count(x => x == yellowLetter);
    if (yellowLetterCount != 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var remainingInputLetters = inputCharArray.Where(x => x != yellowLetter).ToList();
    foreach (var textBoxLetter in textBoxLetters)
    {
        var i = remainingInputLetters.IndexOf(textBoxLetter);
        if (i > -1)
        {
            remainingInputLetters.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return (remainingInputLetters.Count == 0);
}
```

Tests:

```
Word      | Result   | Reason
----------|----------|--------------------
BEEP      | Fail     | Too many 'E's
BUZZ      | Fail     | No 'U's
PEZ       | Pass     |
BEZZ      | Pass     |
QUIZ      | Fail     | No 'U's or 'I's
          | Fail     | (empty)
```